# call a fragment from another class\function kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

1. GameActivity
2. ____FragmentQuest
3. ____FragmentFight
4. class MapLvl.kt

this is a text RPG Fragment Quest displays a journey through different maps (changing the content in one fragment according to a template) text, pictures, navigation buttons. if there is a mob on the map, then the "Fight" button appears and a fragment of the turn-based fight FightFragment opens (hit the head \ legs\ body protect the head \ legs\ body). after the battle, return to QuestFragment

[image]

class MapLvl fills with the content of FightFragment
I need to change QuestFragment from classLvl to FightFragment. how to do it?

**it doesn't work:**
class MapLvl.kt:

```
class MapLevels(){

fun changeLvl (bind: FragmentQuestBinding,hero: Hero, activity: GameActivity,db: Maindb) {
    when (hero.mapLvl) {
        1 -> MapLevels().mapLevel1(bind, activity, hero, db)
        2 -> MapLevels().mapLevel2(bind, activity, hero,db)
        else -> {}
    }
}

    fun mapLevel2 (bind: FragmentQuestBinding,activity: GameActivity,hero:Hero,db: Maindb) {

        bind.btnAtack.visibility= View.VISIBLE

//the problem is here:

        bind.btnAtack.setOnClickListener {
        (activity as GameActivity).supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.placeHolder,FightFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

**error**: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host

QuestFragment:

```
class QuestFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var bind:FragmentQuestBinding
        override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        bind = FragmentQuestBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return bind.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val hero = Hero()
        val db = Maindb.heroSetDb(requireActivity())

        hero.extractHeroData(db,hero)
        scopeMain.launch {
            delay(50)
            MapLevels().changeLvl(bind,hero,GameActivity(),db)
        }
```

if you make a call directly from a Fragment, then it works: (but it is necessary not from the fragment but from the class)

QuestFragment:

```
class QuestFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var bind:FragmentQuestBinding
        override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        bind = FragmentQuestBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return bind.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val hero = Hero()
        val db = Maindb.heroSetDb(requireActivity())

        hero.extractHeroData(db,hero)
        scopeMain.launch {
            delay(50)
            MapLevels().changeLvl(bind,hero,GameActivity(),db)
        }

        bind.btnAtack.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as GameActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.placeHolder,FightFragment.newInstance())
                .commit()
        }
```

it Work:

```
class MapLevels(val bind: FragmentQuestBinding,
                val hero: Hero,
                val db: Maindb,
                val activity: FragmentActivity ){


    fun changeLvl() {
        when (hero.mapLvl) {
            1 -> MapLevels(bind,hero,db,activity).mapLevel1()
            2 -> MapLevels(bind,hero,db,activity).mapLevel2()
            else -> {}
        }
    }
fun mapLevel2() {
        bind.imgLocation.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_loc02)
        bind.txtLocationDiscription.text ="text"

        bind.btnAtack.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        bind.btnAtack.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.placeHolder,FightFragment.newInstance())
                .commit()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. We don't "call" fragments. Nor can you change one fragment to another, really. I think you mean you want to display the contents of QuestFragment. But I'm not quite sure. I recommend that you think about this from the users point of view. What should the user see on the screen when they start the app? What does the user do from there? And what will the user see next?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is a text RPG
Fragment Quest displays a journey through different maps (changing the content in one fragment according to a template) text, pictures, navigation buttons.

if there is a mob on the map, then the "Fight" button appears
and a fragment of the turn-based fight FightFragment opens (hit the head \ legs\ body protect the head \ legs\ body). after the battle, return to QuestFragment

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] your question to include those details. This is entirely doable using the fragment manager. I see you have used it already in the `QuestFragment` to change to the `FightFragment`. You do something similar to go back to the `QuestFragment` after the fighting is done.

Comment: Now that I look at your code more closely, I see a comment "the problem is here:". But what is the problem exactly? What happens when you click this button? What is this `MapLevels` class? It is highly unusual to interact with buttons and other views outside of an activity or fragment class. Maybe that's part of your problem? However, I will need more details before I can give you an answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice https://disk.yandex.ru/i/r53UpC643FUEpQ

Comment: Feel free to add that image to your question, too

Comment: @Code-Apprentice when I click on the "ATACK" button, which is written in the Class file, the activity collapses with an error: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the full error message and stack trace. Also, see my answer below for one thing you need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapLevels().changeLvl(bind,hero,GameActivity(),db)
```

It looks like you are creating a new `GameActivity` instance to pass to your `changeLvl()` method. YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THIS. The new activity is NOT the same one that currently is displayed on the screen. Instead, you should use the `requireAcitivty()` to get the fragment's parent activity:

```
MapLevels().changeLvl(bind,hero,requireActivity(),db)
```

I can't be sure this will fix your current problem because I'm not even sure what the problem is exactly. But it is one issue that you need to change.

Comment: THANK YOU!) I'm a fool. fixed + changed GameActivity to FragmentActivity and it started working) you're super! thank you for your time!